# upsert-kafka connector using to table stream

Tags: apache-flink

Our data is;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxi4s.png)

Currently our are running the next table to be inserted to kafka topic;

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS service_wifi
AS
SELECT CONCAT(TRIM('nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,'),
'method=',`method`,',request_uri=',request_uri_enrich,',country=',country,' ',
'Total_request=',CAST(COUNT(1) AS varchar),
',Total_requestime=',CAST(SUM(request_time) AS varchar),
',Total_code200=',CAST(SUM(Total_code200) AS varchar),
',Total_codeError=',CAST(SUM(Total_codeError) AS varchar),' '
,CAST(timestamp_window AS varchar),'000000000') AS nginx_service
FROM enrich_raw_logs_smartwifi_nginx_service
GROUP BY HOP(ts, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE, INTERVAL '2' MINUTE),`method`,request_uri_enrich,country,timestamp_window;
```

The sink table is created as;

```
create table metrics_out (

out_aggr string,

PRIMARY KEY (out_aggr) NOT ENFORCED

)

with (

'connector' = 'upsert-kafka', -- using kafka connector

'topic' = '....', -- kafka topic

'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '...',

'value.format' = 'raw',

'key.format' = 'raw');
```

And the insert is done as;

```
insert into metrics_out 
SELECT distinct out_aggr from service_wifi;
```

We are expecting the next results;

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=2,Total_requestime=1.89,Total_code200=2,Total_codeError=0 1687169340000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=1,Total_requestime=0.945,Total_code200=1,Total_codeError=0 1687169400000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=3,Total_requestime=2.835,Total_code200=3,Total_codeError=0 1687169340000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=1,Total_requestime=0.945,Total_code200=1,Total_codeError=0 1687169460000000000

However, we are obtaining duplicates where there are not late events;

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=2,Total_requestime=1.89,Total_code200=2,Total_codeError=0 1687169340000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=1,Total_requestime=0.945,Total_code200=1,Total_codeError=0 1687169400000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=3,Total_requestime=2.835,Total_code200=3,Total_codeError=0 1687169340000000000

nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=1,Total_requestime=0.945,Total_code200=1,Total_codeError=0 1687169460000000000

**nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=3,Total_requestime=2.835,Total_code200=3,Total_codeError=0 1687169340000000000**

**nginx_service,bbdd_influx=Service,method=DELETE,request_uri=partner_api,country=es Total_request=1,Total_requestime=0.945,Total_code200=1,Total_codeError=0 1687169460000000000**

It seems that this is happening due to upsert-kafka connector is using changelog stream and we are adding the next property to cleanup the sattes.

set 'table.exec.state.ttl'='240000';

Flink version; 1.15.2

How we are inserted the duplicates rows? could upsert-kafka use table stream instead of changelog?